# Projective fibrations between quasi-projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a smooth surjective morphism between smooth quasi-projective varieties over $\mathbf{C}$. Assume that $f^{-1}(y)\cong \mathbf{P}^1$ for any closed points $y\in Y$.

Question: Is it $f$ proper?

Comment: Yes, that is true and it follows from the "Principle of Connectedness" (roughly Zariski's Main Theorem).  Since the morphism is quasi-projective, $X$ is a dense open of a quasi-projective scheme $\overline{X}$ with a projective morphism to $Y$.  If there exists a geometric point $y$ of $Y$ such that the fiber $\overline{X}_y$ is strictly bigger than $X_y$, use connectedness of $\overline{X}_y$, openness of $X_y$ in $\overline{X}_y$ and closedness of $X_y$ (since $X_y$ is a proper scheme) to get a contradiction.